# How can I avoid putting this variable on the stack?

Tags: c++, arduino, stack, global-variables

I'm currently adapting some example Arduino code to fit my needs.  The following snippet confuses me:

```
// Dont put this on the stack:
uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
```

What does it mean to put the `buf` variable on the stack?  How can I avoid doing this?  What bad things could happen if I did it?

Comment: I think that the comment means that the array should have the static storage duration instead of the automatic storage duration. You can either declare it in a namespace or declare it as a local array with the static specifier depending on the context.

Comment: Depending on the size of `RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN` and the size of the stack available, you could find yourself with a... wait for it... Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program stack has a limited size (even on desktop computers, it's typically capped in megabytes, and on an Arduino, it may be much smaller).

All function local variables for functions are stored there, in a LIFO manner; the variables of your `main` method are at the bottom of the stack, the variables of the functions called in `main` on top of that, and so on; space is (typically) reserved on entering a function, and not reclaimed until a function returns. If a function allocates a truly huge buffer (or multiple functions in a call chain allocate slightly smaller buffers) you can rapidly approach the stack limit, which will cause your program to crash.

It sounds like your array is being allocated *outside* of a function, putting it at global scope. The downside to this is there is only one shared buffer (so two functions can't use it simultaneously without coordinating access, while a stack buffer would be independently reserved for each function), but the upside is that it doesn't cost stack to use it; it's allocated from a separate section of program memory (a section that's usually unbounded, or at least has limits in the gigabyte, rather than megabyte range).

So to answer your questions:

> What does it mean to put the `buf` variable on the stack?

It would be on the stack if it:

1. Is declared in function scope rather than global scope, and
2. Is not declared as `static` (or `thread_local`, though that's more complicated than you should care about right now); if it's declared `static` at function scope, it's basically global memory that can only be referenced directly in that specific function

> How can I avoid doing this?

Don't declare huge non-`static` arrays at function scope.

> What bad things could happen if I did it?

If the array is large enough, you could suffer a stack overflow from running out of available stack space, crashing your program.